# AngularJs Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module schemaForm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, bower

I m trying to add [angular-schema-form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) to [AngularJs Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).
I followed the steps in **angular-schema-form** repository:

#### view1.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute', 'schemaForm'])

  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
      templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
      controller: 'FormController'
    });
  }])


  .controller('FormController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.schema = {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: "string",
          minLength: 2,
          title: "Name",
          description: "Name or alias"
        },
        title: {
          type: "string",
          enum: ['dr', 'jr', 'sir', 'mrs', 'mr', 'NaN', 'dj']
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.form = [
      "*",
      {
        type: "submit",
        title: "Save"
      }
    ];

    $scope.model = {};
  });
```

#### view1.html

```
<div ng-controller="FormController">
    <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="model"></form>
</div>
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#!/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.view1 due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module schemaForm due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'schemaForm' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.8/$injector/nomod?p0=schemaForm
```

Comment: Where did you defined the module _schemaForm_?

Comment: Omg I did a git reset & forgot :/ thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the references for the schemaForm, you need to add it above app.js

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-schema-form/dist/schema-form.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```